# Non-standard source of lead?

Tags: elements

Is there a way to get lead cheaply from local sources? I can buy ingots off eBay and there is a non-ferrous metal supplier I know who sells it for $12 for 5 pounds, but the shipping is nuts.

I considered salvaging lead from a battery, but apparently that is not viable cause the battery is contaminated with a lot of lead oxides, lead carbonates and antimony.

I also considered fishing weights, but I am concerned about alloyed contaminants and also it is getting difficult to find lead fishing weights, especially large ones.

I am interested mostly in "technical grade" just for weighting stuff down (like apparatus stands), but also having a small amount available that is reagent quality.

Comment: If you are at, say, a university - ask around! You might be surprised what folks have on hand. Otherwise, your cost problem with all lead products is the shipping - it is heavy, after all. Perhaps find a local metal supplier and see what they have and can offer.  Since you are concerned about contaminants, that affects all 'non-standard' sources.

Comment: @JonCuster Right, that is something I have considered, sort of Craigslist type of local pickup option. I am asking the question because I thought somebody might know of a common product (not a battery) that I could just pull lead out of for free.

Comment: @ShakaBoom can you pick up from here? http://www.nuclead.com/leadproducts.html

Comment: @DavePhD That's a great find! Thanks for that vendor, I didn't even know they existed. West Bridgewater is a bit of a drive, but not too bad.